# Vuexfire:How many reads does bindFirestoreRef trigger?

Tags: vuexfire

Since I observe an unexpectedly high number of reads I tried to figure out using [the docu](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuexfire.html#firestoreaction) how many reads binding the same document several times triggers.

Suppose I have an action:

```
export const setTodosRef = firestoreAction(
  ({ bindFirestoreRef, unbindFirestoreRef }, documentId) => {
    bindFirestoreRef('documents', db.collection('documents').doc('sameid'))
  }
)
```

What happens, if I call `setTodosRef` 3 times with same document id 'sameid'? Is it 3 or 1?

Is vuexfire smart enough to know that the same document is already bound?

Comment: In the documentation it mention that it unbinds any previously bound reference with the same key. So, I do believe, it will trigger additional reads if you bind to the same document several times.

Comment: I ran a test (`for` loop triggering a few thousand bindings) and this did not show a spike in the read count of a test database. However, it may perfectly be that Vuex does some smart stuff under the hood that catches simple cases like this.